# 2D line intersection collision: Best practices

Tags: c, game-physics, collision

I'm making a 2D platformer game in C. Currently I have a function that casts a ray (a line) from the player in the direction, he is going. I want to use this to check for collisions with, let's say, a wall. My function can take two lines, the direction vector of the player and some other line, and return the point of intersection between them. The collision detection makes sense: Given the current direction and velocity of the player, calculate the distance to the wall as well as the player's position in the next frame. If the next frame's player position's x- or y-value is greater than that of the edge of the wall, move the player a shorter distance than anticipated, so that he does not collide with or go through the wall.

It's the wall, that I'm having trouble with. Since my function uses lines to find the next player position, how can I create the wall's line in an effective manner?
Let's say that my wall entity is a simple rectangle. In one scenario, the player is to the left of the wall, going right. There are 4 rectangles on top of each other forming one larger wall.
Illustration:

[image: Player to the right of 4 wall entities forming one large wall]

In this case, the line, which I'm testing for intersection with the player's line/ray, stretches from the bottom of the bottom-most rectangle to the top of the top-most rectangle, and it is placed on the left side of the rectangles, as shown here:

[image: Red line's intersection with player's vector (line)]

It wouldn't make sense to hardcode these lines. Is there already an algorithm or a technique for this, and does it have a name? No reason to reinvent the wheel here.

Of course, the object the player is colliding with could just as well be the floor, the roof or a wall to the left of the player. So I need to create a function that takes my wall rectangles and calculates where the red line in the picture should be, so I don't have to hardcode it every time.

Best regards

Comment: There is no mention of any APIs, frameworks or performance constraints, so I'm afraid your question is too broad. Try a straightforward move-until-you-collide approach and see how that goes. Collision detect can be done using a pixel map. I've seen pixel-perfect collision detect with 100+ sprites at 60 fps in JavaScript, so a C programmer should have little to worry about.

Comment: Perhaps it is of no concern. I'm using SDL2 as the only API. I'll definitely check out a pixel map. Perhaps checking for collision against all relevant lines is another way to go?  Then later, I guess I could implement a quadtree or something similar. I'm really just looking for ideas